# SQL Server / EF : Decimal value has wrong scale when saving to database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am storing a decimal value in SQL Server using Entity Framework (.net Framework version, C#). I have issues with the precision and scale.

My input number is (30 digits all together):

```
1810.6071428571428571428571429
```

When saving to the DB it becomes:

```
1810.60000
```

I expected it to be:

```
1810.60714
```

Here are the columns in SQL Server:

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of your input number and how are you saving it to database?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `NUMERiC` data type or `decimal` data type

SINCE we need after `.` we need five decimals

```
select convert(numeric(22,5),1810.6071428571428571428571429)
select convert(decimal(22,5),1810.6071428571428571428571429)
```

output

```
1810.60714
```

so

Comment: When you _type_ `1810.6071428571428571428571429` in a query it already is a decimal.